# Expire a Mac OSX App within a certain timeframe and ask the user to update

Tags: macos, cocoa

What's the recommended way to expire a beta Mac OSX app within a certain timeframe (i.e., 14 days) and then ask the user to update (in Cocoa)?

Do I just do date calculations every time the user launches the app?  Also, is there a way to enable to updating using the Sparkle framework if the timeframe has expired?

Thanks

Comment: Using NSUserDefaults and doing some simple calculations on launch might be the best way. I think Sparkle just checks for updates on every launch.

Comment: Does your beta expire at the same date for all users, or do you seek for something more like a demo-version expiration?

Comment: It expires N days after I issue the build to the user.  Right now, I hardcode a date in the future when I build the app (i.e., two weeks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a 14 day rolling beta - i.e. beta expires 14 days after the first run of the application, I would recommend using userDefaults, and checking it at launch.

Specifically, calling isBetaExpired from the code below in your applicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
- (void)setDateForKey:(NSString*)key date:(NSDate*)date {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:date forKey:key];
}

- (NSDate*)getDateForKey:(NSString*)key {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:key];    
}

- (BOOL)isBetaExpired {
    NSString* betaKey = @"v1.0BetaExpireDate";
    double maxElapsed = 60 * 60 * 24 * 14; // 14 days

    NSDate* betaDate = [self getDateForKey:betaKey];
    if (!betaDate) {
        // if we didn't have a beta start date already, set it to now
        betaDate = [NSDate date];
        [self setDateForKey:betaKey date:betaDate];
    }

    // determine how long it has been since the beta started
    double elapsed = [betaDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    // check if it is expired
    BOOL expired = (elapsed >= maxElapsed);

    return expired;
}
```

Comment: @Maverick Note that there is an error in the code posted above that means the beta period will never expire. 

`double elapsed = [betaDate timeIntervalSinceNow];` 

should be 

`double elapsed = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] timeIntervalSinceDate:betaDate];`

Answer (score 6):

I think for a beta that will definitely expire on a given date, you can just hardcode that date. Then you can compare like:

```
NSDate* expirationDate = [NSDate dateWithString: @"2012-03-24 10:45:32 +0600"];
if ([expirationDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    //is expired -> present update recommendation
}
```

If you want to be flexible with the date you could for example create a .txt file on your server wich contains a date-string. That could be easily loaded with:

```
NSString* dateString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
NSDate* expirationDate = [NSDate dateWithString: dateString];
```

It sure would be nice, if you automatically present a sparkle update prompt. You can turn off automatic update checking (see: https://github.com/andymatuschak/Sparkle/wiki/make-preferences-ui ) and then, when the beta time is expired, manually perform an update check and/or reactivate the auto checking. (see: https://github.com/andymatuschak/Sparkle/wiki/customization )

Comment: I like that you also explained how to involve Sparkle in this.